# Сортировка пузырьком на С++

Tags: c++, сортировка, пузырьковая-сортировка

Есть задача: отсортировать пузырьковым методом массив. Есть код. При сортировке происходит нечто: значения не сортируются, а просто перемешиваются.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "TTPtask.h"
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int Score=0;
int Size = 0;
int main() {
    cin >> Size;
    printf("\n");
    int* A = new int[Size];
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
        A[i] = rand();
        cout << A[i] << endl;
    }
    int i = 0;
    int tempCake;
    for (int b = 0; b < Size; b++) {
        for (i; i < Size - 1; i++) {
            if (A[i] > A[i + 1]) {
                tempCake = A[i];
                A[i] = A[i + 1];
                A[i + 1] = tempCake;
                Score++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("SORTED: \n");
    for (int j = 0; j < Size; j++) {
        cout << j+1 << " ";
        cout << A[j] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Воспользуйтесь отладчиком, выполните ваш алгоритм пошагово на каком-нибудь небольшом входном массиве, например, `3 2 1`, понаблюдайте за изменением переменных в процессе работы алгоритма. Особенно за переменной `i`. Особенно обратите внимание на строку `for (i; i < Size - 1; i++)`.

Answer (score 1):

Вот исправленный код

```
for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
    A[i] = rand()%100+1;
    cout << A[i] << endl;
}

int tempCake;

for (int i = 0; i < Size-1; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < Size - 1; j++) {
        if (A[j] > A[j+1]) {
            tempCake = A[j];
            A[j] = A[j+1];
            A[j+1] = tempCake;
            Score++;
        }
    }
}
printf("SORTED: \n");
for (int j = 0; j < Size; j++) {
    cout << j+1 << " "<< A[j] << endl;;
}
```